# Button in a webview without Javascript

Tags: android, button, webview

I have an android application that loads a webview from a server. I do not have the server code so I cannot change anything in Javascript. I want to figure out when a button is being clicked in a webview and what is the label in the button. I do not know the Id, I just want to get the label.

I tried searching for this but could not find an answer. I found solutions where you can work in the javascript but in my case I cannot.

Comment: Just an idea, but you could download the source code and add your own javascript to it, then load it up in the webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggestion may help to find useful information that could lead to determination of your button label. Override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, `shouldInterceptRequest()` and/or `onLoadResource()` for the `WebViewClient` so you can get at the URL of any redirects.

Example:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // Try to learn something useful from the 'url' here.

        // Continue as normal, loading the 'url' within this WebView.
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false; // Allow the WebView to handle the request.
    }

    // Optional: Add similar for "shouldInterceptRequest()" and/or "onLoadResource()".
});
```

**Note**: Overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` as above is the standard way to keep redirects within the same `WebView` rather than redirecting to the default browser application.

Comment: Just one question, how will I know which button is clicked

Comment: That is a very good question, and to find out the answer (if there is one), you will have to experiment with the "url" and other values returned in the three overriden functions that I recommended. I do not know if you can find the button or the button label. But, if this were my problem I would look at all those values in my debugger and/or LogCat and see if I can figure out how to proceed from there.

Comment: Thank you David, I used the url to discover which button was clicked and it is working

Answer (score 0):

You might really want to check this page:

[Building Web Apps in WebView (Google API Guides)](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Specifically, it seems that addJavascriptInterface might be what you are looking for:

[addJavascriptInterface(Object object, String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

It allows you to execute your Java code from javascript and, paired with the ability to insert code in a page, it's an incredibly powerful tool for granting you a high level of coupling between your Activity and your page.

I think that at this point you will already know what to do, but I'll sketch a possible course of action anyway:

- create a javascript interface with the callbacks you want executed in your activity when a button is pressed
- as soon as your page loads, install the code to call your javascript interface in each button (or link) by injection

Hope this helps